# my div is not clickable

Tags: html, css

I would like my div be clickable. but I have tested multi ways that is possible, but it doesn't work fine :

```
 <a href="https://www.telegram.me/shadyab_deal">
 <div  id="mob_link" class="home_right_banner_mob">
    <a href="https://www.telegram.me/shadyab_deal"> <img width="360px" height="130px" src="http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/ic_mob_telegram.jpg"/> </a>
 </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: I jsfiddled your code and it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2ngwbfz7/

Comment: your html structure is wrong, anchor tag not allowed under another anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` is wrong Please used to this

and define your `a` tag `display` `inline-block;`

```css
a{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.telegram.me/shadyab_deal">
     <div  id="mob_link" class="home_right_banner_mob">
        <img width="360px" height="130px" src="http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/ic_mob_telegram.jpg"/>
     </div>
     </a>
```

**2nd option is**  your can used to this valid **HTML**

```css
    #mob_link a{display:block;}
```

```html
 <div  id="mob_link" class="home_right_banner_mob">
    <a href="https://www.telegram.me/shadyab_deal">
            <img width="360px" height="130px" src="http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/ic_mob_telegram.jpg"/>
    </a>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping block level elements with links is allowed in HTML 5. Just do this.

```
<a href="https://www.telegram.me/shadyab_deal">
 <div  id="mob_link" class="home_right_banner_mob">
     <img width="360px" height="130px" src="http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/ic_mob_telegram.jpg"/>
 </div>
 </a>
```